# having difficulty getting a value from a contract with web3

Tags: web3js

I have been trying to replicate the following simple tutorial but deploying to the ropsten network using infura instead of to local host: https://medium.com/coinmonks/interacting-with-ethereum-smart-contracts-through-web3-js-e0efad17977

I am able to set the values in the deployed contract through **setInstructor** via my javascript code and do test gas payments using metamask and ropsten. However, when I try interact with **getInstructor** I get an undefined error. I have pasted my code below. I think the issue may be with the way I've constructed the promise but I am having difficultly resolving it. I am using a promise here as I have deployed to the Ropsten network and there will be a wait before the result.

my solidity contract simply sets and gets values

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract Coursetro {

   string fName;
   uint age;

   function setInstructor(string memory _fName, uint _age) public {
       fName = _fName;
       age = _age;
   }

   function getInstructor() public view returns (string memory, uint) {
       return (fName, age);
   }

}
```

my index.hmtl file takes two inputs and displays the two inputs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="web3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="truffle-contract.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Coursetro Instructor</h1>
        <h2 id="instructor"></h2>
        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Instructor Name</label>
        <input id="name" type="text">
        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Instructor Age</label>
        <input id="age" type="text">
        <button id="button" class="buttman">Update Instructor</button>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my javascript file 'app.js' should set and get values in the contract but only the set works as intended, get returns undefined. The problem is in the retrieveInstructor function

```
  App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},

  init: async function() {

    return await App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: async function() {
    // Modern dapp browsers...
    if (window.ethereum) {
      App.web3Provider = window.ethereum;
      try {
        // Request account access
        await window.ethereum.enable();
      } catch (error) {
        // User denied account access...
        console.error("User denied account access")
      }
    }
    // Legacy dapp browsers...
    else if (window.web3) {
      App.web3Provider = window.web3.currentProvider;
    }
    // If no injected web3 instance is detected, fall back to Ganache
    else {
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/[REDACTED]');
    }
    web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);

    return App.initContract();
  },

  initContract: function() {
    $.getJSON('Coursetro.json', function(data) {
      // Get the necessary contract artifact file and instantiate it with truffle-contract
      var CoursetroArtifact = data;
      App.contracts.Coursetro = TruffleContract(CoursetroArtifact);

      // Set the provider for our contract
      App.contracts.Coursetro.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

    });

    return App.bindEvents();
  },

  bindEvents: function() {
    $(document).on('click', ".buttman", App.handleInstructor);
  },


  handleInstructor: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var setInstructorInstance;

      App.contracts.Coursetro.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        setInstructorInstance = instance;


        return setInstructorInstance.setInstructor($("#name").val(), $("#age").val()) && App.retreiveInstructor();
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      });


   },

   retreiveInstructor: function() {

    var getInstructorInstance;


      App.contracts.Coursetro.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        getInstructorInstance = instance;

        // Promise
            let promise = new Promise(
                    function (resolve, reject) {
                        if (getInstructorInstance.getInstructor()) {


                        resolve(true); // fulfilled
                        } else {
                        var reason = new Error('could not retrieve data');
                        reject(reason); // reject
                        }

                }
            );

        promise.then(
        function(result) { $("#instructor").html(result[0]+' ('+result[1]+' years old)'); },
        function(error) { ; }
        );  



      });
   }

};

$(function() {
  $(window).on('load', function () {
    App.init();
  });
});
```

May I ask what the correct way to write the web3 function to retrieve a value is?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this by changing line

```
resolve(true); // fulfilled
```

to

```
resolve(getInstructorInstance.getInstructor()); // fulfilled
```